# Window left position fail

Tags: c#, wpf, window, position

This is problem is as simple and unexpected for me.
I have a window

```
<Window x:Class="AppWorkFlowExecutor.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppWorkFlowExecutor"
            xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="WF Executor" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="14" PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown"
            WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="False" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" Margin="0"
            Closing="Window_Closing" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" BorderThickness="1"  SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" >
```

and I want it to start in the left upper corner.
But the result is that it is a little more on the right

[image]

in the picture the blue is my background. So I thought that somewhere I have somehow moved it. But when I print the coordinates I get

[image]
and that is correct.
Apparently I have no problem with the top value

Comment: That's because of `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"`. It has a glass "border", which you didn't see (because it's transparent), but it's exists at fact. See **@Rekshimo** solution to change thickness of that "border".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See MSDN:

> Set the GlassFrameThickness property to specify the amount that the
> Windows Aero glass frame extends into the client area of a window. By
> default, the glass frame will use system values to emulate the look of
> a standard window. If Windows Aero is enabled, then the standard
> caption buttons (Maximize, Minimize, Close) are enabled and
> interactive. To make a custom window that does not have a glass frame,
> set this thickness to a uniform value of 0. This will disable the
> standard caption buttons.

Do set glass frame thickness to 0. I have also added `Left="0" Top="0"` to your XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="AppWorkFlowExecutor.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppWorkFlowExecutor"
            xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="WF Executor" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="14" PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown"
            WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="False" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" Margin="0" Left="0" Top="0"
            Closing="Window_Closing" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" BorderThickness="1"  SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" >
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0"></WindowChrome>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: @Patrick You are welcome! :)